# What calamity befell Jesus' Nation?

Tags: history, prophet-isa, quranic-events

Nearly every prophet/messenger came with a warning to his 'nation'. Once that warning has been spread some calamity befalls the disbelievers from that nation. For instance, one well known one is Noah and the flood.

What calamity befell the disbelievers from Jesus' nation?

Answer (score 1):

Prophet Jesus (PBUH) came as a warner to Jews. Jews or Bani-Israel is the nation that originated from Prophet Abraham's (PBUH) son, Prophet Isaac (PBUH).

Before Prophet Abraham (PBUH), individuals were given prophethood but then the whole progeny of Prophet Abraham (PBUH) were given "prophethood".

This is mentioned in [Surah 2 Verse 124](http://quran.com/2/124)

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when Abraham was tried by his Lord with
>   commands and he fulfilled them. [ Allah ] said, "Indeed, I will make
>   you a leader for the people." [Abraham] said, "And of my descendants?"
>   [ Allah ] said, "My covenant does not include the wrongdoers."

But when the jewish nation itself got corrupted, different prophets came to them, the last of them was Prophet Jesus (PBUH). So he came as a warner to a nation that whose was itself a warner. When the jewish nation tried to kill Prophet Jesus (PBUH), Allah saved him and instead of destroying them, they were doomed to eternal subordination.

This is mentioned in [Surah 3 Verse 55](http://quran.com/3/55)

> Mention] when Allah said, "O Jesus, indeed I will take you and raise you to Myself and purify you from those who disbelieve and **make those who follow you [in submission to Allah alone] superior to those who disbelieve until the Day of Resurrection**. ...

To reiterate, **Jewish nation was not destroyed because they are different from other nations as they have been chosen by Allah to be a warner for mankind. The punishment for the crimes is now ethernal subordination.**